# Python if-else-break statement

Tags: python, search, text, line

I need a little help about code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

output = open('XML/epg.xml','w')


with open('SORT/epg_slo_xml.txt','r') as txt:


    for line in txt:

        var1 = 'Program'

        if 'Program' in line:

            if var1 in line !=True:

                var = line
                var_s = '<program>'
                var_stop = '</program>'
                var_uk = var_s+line+var_stop


                if 'Start' in line:
                    var2=line
                    var_s1='<start>'
                    var_stop1 ='</start>'
                    var_uk1 = var_s1+var2+var_stop1
                    var_out = var_uk+var_uk1


                    if 'Duration' in line:
                        var3=line
                        var_s2='<duration>'
                        var_stop2 ='</duration>'
                        var_uk2 =var_s2+var3+var_stop2
                        var_out2= var_uk+var_uk1+var_uk2


                        if 'Title' in line:
                            var4=line
                            var_s3='<title>'
                            var_stop3 ='</title>'
                            var_uk3 =var_s3+var4+var_stop3

                                                        var_out3 =var_uk+var_uk1+var_uk2+var_uk3






output.write('<item>'+var_out3+'</item>')
```

How can I break loop, and when write to output all var_uk statments? Can you give me some advice I've try a lot of things but without result.

My file look's like:

```
Program 10   
        Start   20130918 11:50:00 
        Duration   02:10:00 
              Title Obvestila   
    Program 5   
        Start   20130918 12:00:00 
        Duration   00:20:00 
              Title TV TRANSFRONTALIERA  TG R   
    Program 10   
        Start   20130918 11:50:00 
        Duration   02:10:00 
              Title Obvestila   
    Program 13   
    Program 13   
        Start   20130918 12:00:00 
        Duration   00:15:00 
              Title TV prodaja   
        Start   20130918 12:15:00 
        Duration   01:00:00 
              Title S hrano do vitkosti   
        Start   20130918 13:15:00 
        Duration   00:25:00 
              Title Najini začetki   
        Start   20130918 13:40:00 
        Duration   00:30:00 
              Title Oddamo v najem   
        Start   20130918 14:10:00 
        Duration   01:00:00 
              Title Colin in Justin prenavljata domove
```

I know to write output line by line, for every if statment but how can I write out with all statments?

Comment: `if var1 in line !=True:` doesn't do what you think it does. Both `in` and `!=` are considered comparisons, so Python treats the expression as a chained comparison. It's interpreted as `if var1 in line and line != True:`, which is not what you meant. Just use `if var1 not in line`.

Comment: Just a comment about the line `if var1 in line !=True:`. Its typically more pythonic and easier to understand if you write `if var1 not in line:`. I think the version you used may even give you bad results in some cases.

Comment: Of course, since you assigned `'Program'` to `var1`, and you have the test `if 'Program' in line:`, you already know that `var1` will appear in `line` when you reach the `var1` check, so that doesn't make sense. It's not clear what any of these crazily nested `if`s are supposed to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't entirely understood your problem, break would stop a loop or iteration, I don't see you using it anywhere. But anyway, here are a few tips regarding your code:

1. the line `if var1 in line !=True:` will **never check**, since a line before you are doing `if 'Program' in line:`. var1 equals 'Program' So everything you wrote afterwards will not be run
2. If I understand your code correctly, you're trying to add tags to each line according to content. However, there's no reason to bind them to each other. In your current code (and ignoring the logical error I mentioned), i.e. the 'duration' check only goes if 'start' also checks out. I'm guessing that is not a requirement. Solving that is easy. put all the if conditions on the same indentation level.

like this:

```
`if 'Duration' in line:
     ...code...`

`if 'Title' in line:
     ...code...`
```

3. You're code is very repetative. Essentially all your conditions checks do the same thing, so why not wrap it in a function?

like this:

```
def wrap_tag(line, tag):
    return '<%s>%s</%s>' % (tag, line, tag)
```

then:

```
if 'Start' in line:
     wrap_tag(line, 'start')
```

4. Since it's an XML file, you'd probably be better off using the ElementTree or lxml libraries. They're really good, and easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

How about placing the code you presented in a function? You can then use the `return` statement to exit whenever you please along with you `var_uk` variables in a list.

Also, if you are are parsing XML data then I suggest you look into standard python libraries such as [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).